# Do you say the plural TO or OF something?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

Are these sentences both correct?

> What is the **plural of** boy?
>
> What is the **plural to** boy?

Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Please don't use the backslash when listing alternatives; instead, use the forward slash (`/`).

Comment: Are you asking with regard to a certain version of English?

Answer (score 9):

It’s always *the plural **of** something*.

> What is the plural *of* “boy”?
>
> To make the plural *of* "dog" you add the plural ending -s.
>
> “Are” is the second person plural *of* the verb “to be”.
>
> The word “teeth” is an irregular plural *of* the noun “tooth”.
>
> What's the plural *of* “tooth”?

Comment: But I have seen the sentence:  "there is no singular to audience."

Comment: @Kumarsadhu - You may have seen this, but it’s incorrect. English has a very large number of speakers as a non-native language, and as such, mistakes are extremely common.

Comment: @Kumar sadhu- That is not normal English.  You could get away with 'for', but 'of' is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

> "there is no singular to audience."

This is semantically incorrect - *audience* is a singular word, the plural of which is *audiences* - but syntactically, it's fine. If we instead pick a word like *sheep*, where the same word stands for one or many, then *there is no plural to sheep* is equally as correct as *there is no plural of sheep*.

The use of the different prepositions (*of*, *to*) gives different inflections to the adjective (*singular*). We can see this if we add explicit nouns:

> There is no plural *form of* 'sheep'
>
> There is no plural *equivalent to* 'sheep'

This holds while we are saying *there is no...*. In all the examples so far provided, we are making the adjectives *plural* or *singular* stand in for nouns. If we are asking about the existence of a plural, then *form* makes sense as the noun, but so might *equivalent* or *aspect*, both of which will be happy with a *to*.

In the examples provided by Andrew Tobilko, this would not hold. *of* is the only valid choice in those examples.

Generally, *to* can be used to relate qualities to objects. For example, it's natural and correct to say *there is no flavour to this food* - especially if you are a visitor to Britain.

Comment: +1 for the joke in the final paragraph.

Comment: Note that 'equivalent' is an adjective in a reduced relative phrase: "There is no plural [that is] equivalent to 'sheep'."  If it was parsed as a noun (with 'plural' as adjective) then 'to' is just as clunky as "There is no plural to 'sheep'."

Comment: An excellent and germane clarification, thank you!